# Configure Outlook autocomplete to use/prefer a particular contact?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autocomplete, microsoft-outlook-2016

When I send a new email, it's usually to the same four or five people.  However, Outlook autocomplete never seems to recognize that when I type "TJ" I usually want a particular TJ to either simply autocomplete or be the default selected entry for the auto complete dialog.

I would very much like to have to stop selecting the third address book entry down off the list every time I send an email to TJ!  :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not feasible to configure Autocomplete to prefer a particular contact. For your situation, you may consider using the X to remove the first two addresses from the Autocomplete popup as a workaround.